# Firestore onSnapshot updates and adds array to the DOM instead of only updating

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have data from Firestore that I'm mapping to the DOM and then updating client-side. While the data is updating how I want, every time the event fires, another updated array is added to the DOM.

I'm thinking the issue is with the how the click events are set up, but I'm not sure how else I can apply my client-side actions otherwise on the array.

here's my setup and click event

```js
function App() {
  const [heroesArr, setHeroesArr] = useState([]);
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const onFetch = () => {
    const newHeroes = [];
    db.collection("characterOptions").onSnapshot(coll => {
      coll.forEach(doc => {
        const { Name, uidDownvoted, uidUpvoted, votes } = doc.data();
        newHeroes.push({
          key: doc.id,
          doc,
          Name,
          uidDownvoted,
          uidUpvoted,
          votes
        });
      });
      setHeroesArr(newHeroes);
    });
  };

  const onUpVote = i => {
    const collRef = db.collection("characterOptions");
    setHeroesArr(heroesArr =>
      heroesArr.map((item, o) => {
        if (i === o && !item.uidDownvoted && !item.uidUpvoted) {
          collRef.doc(item.key).update({
            votes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
            uidUpvoted: true
          });
        } else if (i === o && !item.uidDownvoted && item.uidUpvoted) {
          collRef.doc(item.key).update({
            votes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
            uidUpvoted: false
          });
        } else if (i === o && item.uidDownvoted && !item.uidUpvoted) {
          collRef.doc(item.key).update({
            votes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(2),
            uidUpvoted: true,
            uidDownvoted: false
          });
        }
        return item;
      })
    );
  };
```

and here's the markup

```js
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={onFetch}>click</button>
      {heroesArr.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={item.key}>
          <p>{item.Name}</p>
          <p>{item.votes}</p>
          {item.uidDownvoted && <p>this has been downvoted</p>}
          {item.uidUpvoted && <p>this has been upvoted</p>}
          <button onClick={() => onUpVote(i)}>Upvote</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

I'm obviously just expecting the array to update, not to create an additional updated copy every time the click event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Always clear the array
2. Perform incremental updates

Since the first option is the simplest, I'll show you the code for that.

Right now, you declare your `newHeroes` outside of the `onSnapshot`, even though you only use it inside of it. This means that every time you loop over `coll.forEach()` you're adding all elements to `newHeroes`, including elements that you had read before.

The simplest option is to declare `newHeroes` inside the callback, so that it starts empty each time the callback runs.

```
db.collection("characterOptions").onSnapshot(coll => {
  const newHeroes = [];
  coll.forEach(doc => {
    const { Name, uidDownvoted, uidUpvoted, votes } = doc.data();
    newHeroes.push({
      key: doc.id,
      doc,
      Name,
      uidDownvoted,
      uidUpvoted,
      votes
    });
  });
  setHeroesArr(newHeroes);
});
```

An alternative is to use the information that Firestore gives you about what documents are new, which ones are updated, etc. To get this information, you need to loop over `coll.documentChanges`. For an example of this, see the documentation on [view changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).